# Visual Studio 2017 15.5 Breaks C++ TypeDefs

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I had an issue whereupon updating Visual Studio 2017 to 15.5 resulted in compile-time errors for a previously function C++ application.

Specifically, it was unable to properly parse the defined type-definitions as it had before, and the constructors and method arguments that utilized them were creating syntax errors at compile-time.

Example:

```
template <class T>
class Demo
{
public:
    typedef Demo<T> DEMO;

public:
    template <class T>
    class NestedDemo { };

public:
    typedef DEMO::NestedDemo<T> NESTED_DEMO;

private:
    NESTED_DEMO _attribute;

public:
    inline DEMO(NESTED_DEMO attribute)
        : _attribute(attribute)
    { }
};
```

Where the error message would be: "syntax error: missing ')' before the identifier 'attribute'" with the compile error: C2146.

Edit:
Fixed typo in example.

Edit:
Fixed another typo.

Edit:
Here is an image of the example failing to compile:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO9aA.jpg

Comment: That type definition definitely looks ill-formed... You're using `K` which wasn't declared anywhere.

Comment: Can't repro because K is undefined. One thing you can try is to leave Conformance Mode on, but use ``/Zc:twoPhase-`` in the Additional Options to disable just [two phase name lookup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/09/11/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/).

Comment: Sorry, this was not copy-pasted but typed out to as an example. I used K as the template variable in my code but T in the example. So I instinctively used K where I meant to use T in the example.

@Sneftel

Comment: With various other syntax errors fixed (see https://godbolt.org/z/qTjfI4 ), the code compiles fine on MSVC 2017 even with `/permissive-`.

Comment: There may be something else going on that I am unaware of. I was able to replicate the issue with the example provided:

https://imgur.com/a/KO1m6fJ

The capture was with the permissive setting enabled, and upon setting the value to "NO" I was able to compile with no issue.

@Sneftel

Answer (score 0):

Using type-definitions is now what MSVC defines as not being "[close] to C++ standards conformance," and are as such no longer syntactically valid when compiling.

Thankfully, this is something we can disable.

MSVC 2017 v15.5 added this option, and several others, into the project's properties. While I do not know if there are other ways around this, this is the option used to disable the standards-conformance:

> "C/C++ > Language > Conformance Mode" (defaults to "Yes
>   (/permissive-)" after updating)

Changing the value to "No" will resolve the problem.

For those interested, here is the blog post on the update:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/11/15/msvc-conformance-improvements-in-visual-studio-2017-version-15-5/

And here is the doc on the option in question:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=vs-2017